# Local authentication for login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

So i'm developing a coding website , where the user needs to login and then on successfull login he will be directed to another page where he needs to type code for the question asked .

So this is how my login page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<head>
    <title>SIGN IN PAGE</title>
    
    
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="login-box">
    
  <div class="left">
      
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>

    <form id="new_form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id = "name" placeholder="Name" required/>
    <br/>
    <input style="text-decoration:none" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id = "email" required/>
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id = "password" required/>
    <br/>
      
    <button type = "submit" id = "submitbtn" style="width: 120px; height: 30px; background:#16a085;"><!---<a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">---> LOGIN</a></button>
  </form> 
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#new_form").submit(function(){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/login_info/",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: {"name": name,"email":email,"password":password},
                    success:function(response){
                      alert("Redirecting to main page");
                      
                        console.log(response);
                        try{
                            var resp = JSON.parse(response);
                            
                            if(resp.status=="ok"){
                                //alert("Data sent");
                                if(!name || !email || !password)
                                {
                                  alert("Please enter all the fields");
                                }
                                else{
                                window.location="http://localhost:8080";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("Something went wrong\nError:"+resp.msg);
                               
                            }
                        }catch(err){
                            alert("Invalid Response Got From Server");
                        }
                        //console.log(response);
                    },
                    error:function(err,xhr,msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        })


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my main coding page looks like :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>CODE TEST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="question">
            <h2><strong>QUESTION 01:</strong></h2>
            Find the maximum number in an array of integers.
            <br/> For example, in the array [1, -3, 5], the maximum number is 5.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <h2>OUTPUT</h2>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="60" id="results" style="background-color: black;color: white;"  readonly></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="code-area">
            <select id="language">
                <option value="c" selected>C</option>
                <option value="c++">C++</option>
            </select>

            <textarea rows="20" class="input" id="code" name="codearea" style="background-color: black;color: white;" autofocus></textarea>
            <br/><br/>
            <button id="submitBtn">SUBMIT</button>
            <br/><br/>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
                var code = $("#code").val();
                var lang = $("#language").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/codetest/",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: {"code": code,"lang":lang},
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        try{
                            var resp = JSON.parse(response);
                            if(resp.status=="ok"){
                                alert("Compiled Successfully");
                                $("#results").val(resp.result);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("Error for the above code is \n:");
                                var error_message = resp.msg;
                                var str_pos = error_message.indexOf("input_code");
                                if (str_pos > -1)
                                {
                                    
                                    var replaced_string = error_message.replace(/input_code.c.......|Error.*/gm,'');
                                 
                                    $("#results").val(replaced_string);

                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("Not found");

                                }
                                
                            }
                        }catch(err){
                            alert("Invalid Response Got From Server");
                        }
                        //console.log(response);
                    },
                    error:function(err,xhr,msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        $("#results").val(msg);
                        alert("Network Issue");
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the Node.js file which takes the input from both the pages and stores it in mongodb and also compiles and throws the output for the code typed .

So here is the Node.js file :-

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;
const express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const expressSession = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
});



var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";



var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();

const app = express();  
const CODE_FOLDER = "";

function login_info(req,res){
  
  let name = req.body["name"];
  let email = req.body["email"];
  let password = req.body["password"];

   MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var myobj = { name: name, email: email,password: password };
  dbo.collection("login_info").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("document inserted");
    db.close();

    
  });
  return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":"ok"}));
});
  
}


function testCode(req, res) {
  let code = req.body["code"];

  let option_selected = req.body["lang"];
  console.log(option_selected);

  if(option_selected == "c++")
  {

                      try {
                        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, CODE_FOLDER, "input_code.cpp"), decodeURIComponent(code));
                        const proc = exec("g++ input_code.cpp -o input_code && ./input_code");
                        //const proc1 = exec("./a.out")
                        const results = proc.toString();

                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":"ok","result":results}));
                      } 
                      catch (err) {
                        console.log("An error occurred");
                        console.log(err);
                        var error1 = err.toString();
                        console.log("Here is the error");
                        console.log(error1);
                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":"FATAL_ERROR","msg":err.toString()}));
                      }
}
if(option_selected == "c")
{
                      try {
                        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, CODE_FOLDER, "input_code.c"), code);
                        const proc = exec("gcc input_code.c -o input_code && ./input_code");
                        const results = proc.toString();

                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":"ok","result":results}));
                      } 
                      catch (err) {
                        console.log("An error occurred");
                        console.log(err);

                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":"FATAL_ERROR","msg":err.toString()}));
                      }
}

}

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/page02.html'));
});

app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/page01.html'));
});

app.post('/codetest/', testCode);
app.post('/login_info/',login_info);



app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Listening on port.`),);
```

So the url to my login page is :- http://localhost:8080/login

and the url to main coding page is :- http://localhost:8080

So now any user can view my main coding page without logging-in , so i need to prevent this happening and display a message saying that you have to log-in .

So is there any way , where i can only allow the user to see the coding page when he enters his details in the login page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, when posting on Stack Overflow, trim out anything that's not essential to understanding the problem. This CSS is just taking up a ton of space and has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Is this an Express app? If so, why do you have *so much* inline styling? This looks like it's missing the point of a server-side framework like Express. You should be using something like Webpack or Parcel to consolidate your static assets (JavaScript, CSS, etc.) to keep your view code as minimal and maintainable as possible. What you have here is just a giant mess of CSS, HTML, and JavaScript that seems to have no connection to Node at all.

Comment: The way you wall things off with an authentication layer is to ensure everything runs through your Express app, that these aren't just static files you're serving up. This is done by having handlers before routes that check for authentication and kick to the login page if no session is found.

Comment: really sorry for the initial post , now I have a edited and required code put up here

Comment: Using `sendFile` is a last resort. You should have a better way of doing that with [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) and the [view/template system of your choice](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). Using static files is a huge mess as you'll have to copy-paste repeat everything, which sort of misses the point.

Comment: It sounds like you need to review the [Passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) and follow their guidelines on restricting access to routes.

Answer (score -1):

After login you have to generate authentication token and save that token in cookies. Whenever any user directly go to that page just check the cookies exist or have not expired. if everything goes fine then allow then to access that page otherwise redirect to login page. This is the flow of checking. You can use JWT for authentication token

Comment: hi shubham could you please provide some links where I can refer how its done

Comment: hi, I see someone negative my answer, I thought you don't like my answer.....Yes here is the reference of a video, you can check this, if you need any other help please let me know. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYCzSI3Qi0Y

Comment: No it wasnt me who marked it as negative ....i'm just looking for implementations to try

Comment: Okay, No problem just try that.

Comment: Hi shubham , i tried did not work out , the main problem is i'm not registering the user rather he has to just login